# What does postfic in the wallet transaction id mean

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, dash, transaction-id

It's known the txid is always a 32 byte hex sequence for example `ceca9c54d1a2f9122326a871a3b0b20b725540137e80cb50da663a404f7849a8`, but when inpecting the transaction in a wallet it shows it with a dash and three number postfix :

[image]

What does `-000` mean in the `txid`, and why is it there?

Answer (score 1):

It means this receive is due to output number 0 of the listed transaction.

Transactions can have multiple outputs (and usually do), and it is possible that more than one of them pays you. If that is the case, they will be listed as separate "transactions" in the UI, but their output will be distinct.

Comment: so, does it means that 00 is the index of vout in the raw transaction?

Comment: Correct, that's it.